# How to make a Python Wrapper for the following .cpp file in visual studio project?

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, wrapper, swig

```
# include <boost/python.hpp>
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
# include <vector>
# include <D:\Users\212334548\Personal\QuantLib-1.2.1\ql\quantlib.hpp>
# include <ctime>
# include <stdlib.h>

using namespace QuantLib;
using namespace boost::python;

class interpolation
{
public:
    interpolation()
    {
    };
    ~interpolation()
    {
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> linearonrates(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding,int size)
    {
        int n = size;
        std :: vector <double > xVec (n) , yVec (n);
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            xVec[i] = data[i][0];
            yVec[i] = data[i][1];
        }
        LinearInterpolation linInt ( xVec . begin (), xVec . end (), yVec . begin ());
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        for(int i = xVec[0] ; i<=xVec[n-1] ; i+=1000)
        {
            //std :: cout << linInt (i) << std :: endl ;
            std::vector<double> row;
            row.push_back(i);
            row.push_back(linInt(i));
            vec.push_back(row);
        }
        return vec;
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> linearonlogrates(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding,int size)
    {
        int n = size;
        std :: vector <double > xVec (n) , yVec (n);
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            xVec[i] = data[i][0];
            yVec[i] = std::log(data[i][1]);
        }
        LinearInterpolation linInt ( xVec . begin (), xVec . end (), yVec . begin ());
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        for(int i = xVec[0] ; i<=xVec[n-1] ; i+=1000)
        {
            //std :: cout << linInt (i) << std :: endl ;
            std::vector<double> row;
            row.push_back(i);
            row.push_back(std::exp(linInt(i)));
            vec.push_back(row);
        }
        return vec;
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> linearondiscountfactors(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        //code here
        return vec;
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> linearonlogdiscountfactors(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        //code here
        return vec;
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> cubiconrates(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        //code here
        return vec;
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> cubiconlogrates(double** data,int daycount,char* holiday,char* compounding)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
        //code here
        return vec;
    };

};

int main()
{
    //code here ...
    ///*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double **data;//= {{0,3.4},{2000,4.5},{4000,6.0},{8000,7.8},{16000,9.6}};
    data = new double*[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        data[i] = new double[2];
    }
    data[0][0] = 0.0;
    data[0][1] = 3.4;
    data[1][0] = 2000.0;
    data[1][1] = 4.5;
    data[2][0] = 4000.0;
    data[2][1] = 6.0;
    data[3][0] = 8000.0;
    data[3][1] = 7.8;
    data[4][0] = 16000.0;
    data[4][1] = 9.6;
    int daycount = 360;
    char* holiday = "None";
    char* compounding = "Continuous";
    interpolation *inter = new interpolation();
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec = inter->linearonlogrates(data,daycount,holiday,compounding,5);
    //std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
    //std::cout <<"data : "<< vec;
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout <<vec[i][0]<< "\t" << vec[i][1]<<"\n";
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    double tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;

    return 0;

}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(InterP)
{   
    class_<interpolation>("interpolation")
        .def("linearonrates", &interpolation::linearonrates)
    ;
}
```

This is the code, in which I am trying to use boot-python to make the wrapper. If I remove the last six lines, all seems to work fine. But on including the lines, linkage errors like following are generated :

```
>interpolation.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct boost::python::converter::registration const & __cdecl boost::python::converter::registry::lookup(struct boost::python::type_info)" (__imp_?lookup@registry@converter@python@boost@@YAABUregistration@234@Utype_info@34@@Z) referenced in function "struct boost::python::converter::registration const & __cdecl boost::python::converter::detail::registry_lookup2<class interpolation const volatile >(class interpolation const volatile & (__cdecl*)(void))" (??$registry_lookup2@$$CDVinterpolation@@@detail@converter@python@boost@@YAABUregistration@123@P6AADVinterpolation@@XZ@Z)
1>d:\users\212334548\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wrap_interpolation\Debug\wrap_interpolation.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 32 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Is this the same as your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313015/c-python-wrapper If so, I'd suggest combining the two into one (as well as transforming the code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Hi @jogojapan,
Its a related question to my previous question. Its almost the same, just the difference is that now I have tried all i could to write the wrappers and desperately need help.

Comment: Then the two questions need to be combined. You can easily do this by deleting the other one and adding the linker error messages to this one here. Also, I suggest that you simplify your code to a **minimal** example: Perhaps a class with just one empty or super-simple function. Try to build that and check what the linker says.

Comment: @jogojapan, I have deleted the old question. Now if you can provide some more helpful tips towards how to solve the problem, it would be really great of you.
here's the error I am getting when I am trying to write a wrapper using boost-python.
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'